# when to use source filtering and when to use fields? Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I read about two ways to filter the fields returned by elasticsearch. [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) And [source filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html). when to use which?

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the complete document (using `"_source" : {"enabled" : true}`) then **source filtering** can be used.

If you store individual fields (using `"store" : true`) then use **fields**.
However if the individual field isn't found then **fields** will get the data from the _source anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above comment , 
fields are usually used when _source is too large and i am only interested in certain fields alone. For eg: , i might a document each for news. The news might contain title , content and URL. I would like to search on title or content but just return the URL's . In doing so , you just get what you are looking for and some of the network latency would be saved in transporting back the response.